# MSSQL Connection from IIS7

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssl, iis-7

VS is a pain in the ass.

When debugging with IIS Express - without creating SSL certificates or anything - everything works fine: DB connection, AD connection, SQL connection.
When sending everything on IIS 7 with self-signed certificate, nothing works, everything throws errors, and I am left alone without VS debugging tools.

How come the following code

```
        dbconn = new SqlConnection("user id=test;password=test;server=server01;Trusted_Connection=true;TrustServerCertificate=true;database=test;connection timeout=5");
        try
        {
            dbconn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Message("dbconn.open failed: " + e.Message);
        }
```

works when run on my dev machines, but on IIS7 on server03 it returns

```
dbconn.open failed: Login failed for user 'INTRA\SERVER03$'.
```

Especially why is the user 'INTRA\SERVER03$' (which does not exist, btw), and not the user I explicitly specified in the connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the connection string, that should be set to:

```
user id=test;password=test;server=server01;TrustServerCertificate=true;database=test;connection timeout=5
```

After this is done, the next problem may be that "the SELECT permission was denied", which was the case because my sql user "test" was not set to db_datareader for database "test" (in SSMS under Security => Logins).

This gives me a nice follow-up question: *Why the heck did it work at all in IIS Express?*